# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

PHP Fatal error:

```
Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in /home/public_html/edulite/lib/Cake/Core/Object.php on line 31
```

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.5 Version. How can i fix this error?

Comment: This was fixed in 2.9.0 - released 2016-10-18. Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: How can i update the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix I found from [their github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11830).

This issue was officially fixed in version 2.9.0, which was released 10/18/2016. I highly recommend that you update to a newer versio instead of the fix below.

---

Fix from Github:

Remove line 18 in `Object.php`

```
// class_alias('CakeObject', 'Object');
```

and change line 16 in `CakeMigration.php` to

```
class CakeMigration extends CakeObject {
```

Comment: I don't have a this kind of line in object.php (https://pastebin.com/Ks9CEDbp)
and i don't have a CakeMigration.php